# SQL Server error on stored procedure parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I'm getting a SQL Server error on a stored procedure (although it appears to run and run correctly).  When I view the stored procedure call in my code, it is underlined, and the highlighted error message says: "Procedure sp_ReferenceSite has no parameters and arguments were supplied."

My procedure is called like this:

```
execute dbo.sp_ReferenceFieldwork @refColumnName='Comment', @FldWkID=@FieldInvId, @reference=@ref output
```

and the procedure is defined as

```
CREATE  PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_ReferenceFieldwork]
@refColumnName varchar(100),
@FldWkID int,
@reference varchar(8000) output
AS
```

As far as I can tell, all the cases are correct, the number of parameters are correct, the field types are correct.  What's the problem?  Or, at least, what might be the problem?

Comment: Is this Intellisense giving an error?

Comment: Yes, from within SQL-Server Managment Studio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it runs OK, then it's probably the Intellisense cache.

[How to refresh it](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dtjones/archive/2008/09/11/refreshing-the-intellisense-cache.aspx)

It's brain dead: take it outside and shoot it. Replace with Redgate SQL prompt or similar.

Comment: `CTRL+SHIFT+R` will refresh the Intellisense cache.

Comment: @JNK: Thanks. I *despise* it and use SQL prompt :-)

Comment: I've heard that's better but in my environment we are using standard MS tools for the most part :(